# Is there a way to correctly count number of days in 1582

Tags: java, sql, date, calendar, gregorian-calendar

How would one calculate a number of days in 1582. Yes, that is the year of introduction of the Georgian Calendar (in some countries). I assume October 1582 should not have 31 days as some of the dates never existed.

Yet when I tried Joda Time (Java/Groovy) it says 30 days:

```java
LocalDate start = new LocalDate("1582-10-01");
LocalDate end = new LocalDate("1582-10-31");
println Days.daysBetween(start, end).getDays();
```

Same for SQL

```sql
-- PostgreSQL
SELECT DATE_PART('day', '1582-10-31'::date - '1582-10-01'::timestamp);
   
-- MSSQL
SELECT DATEDIFF(dd, '1582-10-31', '1582-10-01');
```

So is there some agreement/specification to actually treat 1582-10-14 as if it would actually exist? Or is there some easy way to calculate correct diff for year 1582 and earlier?

Comment: Rephrase the question, "how can I get the number of days in 1582 using c" or whatever language

Comment: Note: most calendar libraries (and so also programming languages) have just an interval where you can perform date operations. As far I know, many languages just use Gregorian Calendar for all years, also before it was introduced. Just do not use generic functions for historical dates: it requires much more context which modern API will not provide, and mostly not useful in modern calendars)

Comment: @GiacomoCatenazzi But in Gregorian Calendar date 1582-10-14 does not exist. AFAIK the calendar jumped through a few days in October.

Comment: No. Gregorian Calendar is a principally a method. It was decided to implement it. So with such steps: leaving the Julian calendar, skipping dates (to keep equinox on standard calendar dates), and introducing the Gregorian calendar. People applied the Gregorian calendar also backward: there is no problem in that. If the 14 October 1582 was nonexistent on some territories is a different problem. it was the date on the "wall", not the Gregorian date, that was nonexistent.

Comment: @GiacomoCatenazzi Interesting opinion, but Java devs wouldn't agree with you. You cannot create 14th October. At least not with GregorianCalendar: https://replit.com/@MaciejNux/Gregorian-Calendar-date-holes#Main.java

Comment: The original document explicitly says "we direct and ordain: that ten days shall be removed from the month of October of the year 1582" https://en.wikisource.org/wiki/Translation:Inter_gravissimas (translated original)

Comment: About the first comment: Java developers choose a starting point (and a internal representation). Unix a different one, windows an other one, Excel a different one, Python and other languages recommend not to use old dates (more then 50 or 100 year ago). it is an implementation choice. As I wrote on my first comment: do not assume thing works on such dates.

Comment: And second comment: you cite the part where it say wall dates should be skip and then Gregorian calendar should be used. It doesn't say that dates before October were Gregorian, etc. Note: England and US had such dates. They switched much later to Gregorian calendar. You should distinguish the "wall dates" (so dates you may see on the wall of a church, castle, market), and the method ("ever 4 year, but every 100 but every 400")

Comment: If the precise wall date is that important for years prior to 1853, write a super class to convert a Gregorian date to a Gregorian/Julian date.

Comment: Joda-Time can do that stuff.  Joda-Time as its default uses the proleptic Gregorian calendar, extrapolating the Gregorian calendar back in the times before it was invented, pretending October 1582 is 31 days as always, But it also supports the Gregorian-Julian chronology. Create your dates as `new LocalDate(1582, 10, 1, GJChronology.getInstance())` and similar for the end of the month. Then Joda-Time knows that this October is 10 days shorter.

Answer (score 2):

I have not used Java in many years, but I am familiar with dealing with several calendars in other languages. From the "Key Concepts" subtab of the "Documentation" tab of the [Joda Time website](https://www.joda.org/joda-time/index.html) we find the ["Chronology" page](https://www.joda.org/joda-time/key_chronology.html) which states

> The default chronology in Joda-Time is ISO. This calendar system is
> the same as that used by business in the majority of the world today.
> The ISO system is unsuitable for historical work before 1583 as it
> applies the leap year rules from today back in time (it is a proleptic
> calendar). As a result, users requiring a more historically accurate
> calendar system are forced to think about their actual requirements,
> which we believe is a Good Thing.

Proleptic means that from a known day and date that virtually everyone agrees about, such as the Meter Convention having been signed in Paris on 20 May 1875, the rules of the calendar are applied backward to find any date desired, even if it is before the calendar was created.

As for computing the interval in one calendar, such as the Julian calendar, to a date in a different calendar, such as the Gregorian calendar, a common approach is to convert them both to a count-of-days from a chosen epoch, such as the [modified julian date](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Julian_day#Variants), which counts from midnight universal time at the beginning of November 17, 1858. Then one simply subtracts one day count from the other to find the number of days between them. A quick glance at the Joda Time documentation did not show any facility for computing a day count.

I am currently not set up to program in Java. Ole V.V. comment about using the Gregorian-Julian chronology of Joda-Time seems useful, but I have not tried it:

```
LocalDate first = new LocalDate(1582, 10, 1, GJChronology.getInstance());
LocalDate last = new LocalDate(1582, 10, 31, GJChronology.getInstance());
int countOfDaysDiff = Days.daysBetween(first, last).getDays();
System.out.println(countOfDaysDiff);
```

Output according to Ole V.V.:

> 20

Comment: Did you try my suggestion in the comment? *Create your dates as new `LocalDate(1582, 10, 1, GJChronology.getInstance())` and similar for the end of the month. Then Joda-Time knows that this October is 10 days shorter.* (That’s `GJChronology` for Gregorian-Julian.)

Comment: I am currently not set up to program in Java. Ole V.V. comment seems useful, but I have not tried it.

Answer (score 0):

I think I will go ahead and close with that both answers are probably correct. October 1582 did and didn't have 31 days. I mean that 14th October didn't exist (as in no one was born on that day in Gregorian Calendar) and for the purpose of accounting all debts were pushed by ten days. So I guess the only way is to manually count days and don't use any libraries for that.

When establishing Gregorian Calendar it was said that:

> we direct and ordain:
> that ten days shall be removed from the month of October of the year 1582

But also:

> But in order that nobody suffers prejudice by this our subtraction of ten days, in connection with any annual or monthly payments, the judges in any controversies that may arise over this, shall by reason of the said subtraction add ten days to the due date for any such payment.

Source: https://en.wikisource.org/wiki/Translation:Inter_gravissimas