# Selected date in a datetime-local input is wrong for date prior to 15 October 1582

Tags: android, google-chrome, datetime, datepicker, julian-date

My HTML5 project works on historical events that stand before the switch from Julian to Gregorian Calendar in october 1582.

Using a simple `<input type="datetime-local"/>` html node to retrieve a user selected date I have this unconvenient behavior with Android Google Chrome browser :

1. The user select with the chrome datepicker widget a date prior to 1582 (ex : 1572-04-01).
2. After selection, the input display a date 10 days in the futur (ex : 1572-04-11).

Since when manipulating the widget, it avoids the 10 days gap between 05 and 14 october 1582, I assume it sends back to the input a Gregorian Calendar converted date from the Julian Calendar "displayed in widget" one.

The issue, obviously, is the user is not getting the numbers he has selected.

Meanwhile, the windows chrome version doesn't seem to care about Julian - Gregorian gap at all and is consistent between datepicker and input value.

I've made a test page [here](https://inside.42web.io/DatePickerTest.html) with a preselected date prior the calendar type change.

How can I check if this behavior happened in order to correct it with a javascript afterward ?
Is there a an obscure html or css specific vendor tag that somehow fix the problem ?

I'm all ears.

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74353924/is-there-a-way-to-correctly-count-number-of-days-in-1582